# what file/folder is used in mean.js to include additional js scripts

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

Just started using Mean.js boiler plate.
Added a new module named "datacollectors" to represent my specific business logic.
This module depends on a number of Angular services, such as angular-route, etc...
Under my public/modules/datacollectors   I have modified the default "registerModule" line to include my dependency:

```
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('datacollectors',['ngRoute']);

Ran bower install angular-route --save`
```

When I refreshed the app in the browser, I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module datamanager-02 due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module datacollectors due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I do have angular-route installed under public/lib, but I do not know which file or directory mean.js uses to load any additional .js file.

Normally, this would be done by including   tags in the index.html file, but mean.js boiler plate is not structured that way.

My question is:   Where exactly do I specify all the additional js scripts in their proper order of loading within the mean.js structure?

Comment: Found it: all css and js are being listed in their repsctive loading order in config/env/all.js

Comment: try this one https://github.com/kevalbhatt/mean-js